# PHP leave only Specific multidimensional Array, if element is equal to String

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, filter

I have a multi-dimensional array with two inner multi-dimensional arrays. I have multiple data in the uppermost array and what I want to do is only filter out the uppermost array indexes that has the given string in the inner array's value.

The array will be:

```
Array [Upper_1]
(
    [Inner_1] => {a => 111}, {b => 222}, {c => 333}
    [Inner_2] => {a => aaa}, {b => bbb}, {c => ccc}
)
Array [Upper_2] 
(
    [Inner_1] => {a => 777}, {b => 888}, {c => 999}
    [Inner_2] => {a => xxx}, {b => yyy}, {c => zzz}
)
given_string = yyy
```

So if [Upper 2] array's [Inner_2{b}] has the matching value with the given string, I want to delete the remaining [Upper 1] array index.

I have no working code so far so I apologize in advance for not posting code.

Comment: And what have you tried so far?

Comment: you want to remove the element that does not contain the value? upper 1 in your example?

Comment: I don't think I understand this question.  Are you saying that you want to search `Upper_2`'s rows of data in search of an element with the value `yyy`.  Then when you find its first level key (`Inner_2`) and its second level key (`b`), you want to remove the row with the key `Inner_2` in the `Upper_1` array?

Answer (score 0):

```
function delete_col(&$array, $key) {
    return array_walk($array, function (&$v) use ($key) {
        unset($v[$key]);
    });
}
```

once you know the key you need to remove you can use this.

or if your just keeping a few elements, create a new array to hold them..

as far as finding the element to keep/remove.. do you need help with that also?